# When writing an Outlook 2013 Add-In to change the Follow-Up options, why are they always empty?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

In Outlook 2013, I'm trying to write an add-in that manipulates the Follow Up options upon sending an email.

[image: Follow up options]

If I use the above UI to set the follow up flag in the message I sent, then hook into the ItemSend event

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
        this.Application.ItemSend += Application_ItemSend;            
    }

    void Application_ItemSend(object item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
        DateTime x1 = mailItem.TaskStartDate;  // 1/1/4051
        DateTime x2 = mailItem.TaskDueDate;  // 1/1/4051
        DateTime x3 = mailItem.TaskCompletedDate;  // 1/1/4051
        DateTime x4 = mailItem.ReminderTime;  // 1/1/4051
        bool x5 = mailItem.ReminderSet;  // false
        DateTime x6 = mailItem.ToDoTaskOrdinal;  // 1/1/4051
        bool x7 = mailItem.IsMarkedAsTask; // false
        bool x8 = mailItem.Submitted; // false
        string x9 = mailItem.FlagRequest; // null
        string subject = mailItem.Subject; // this value matches the subject of the email correctly
```

I get the values in the comment above.  None of the Dates as in the screenshot of Outlook's UI (valued May 7, 2015) appear in the MailItem object.

Where do these values live?  Why aren't they valued as I'd expect on the MailItem object?

Comment: My standard question for anyone working with Outlook add-ins: Do you know about OutlookSpy? http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm It might help.

Comment: Try to save the mail item first before hitting the Send button. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

During the ItemSend event, these properties have empty values.  However, by watching the Sent Items folder via

```
var sentitems = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Items;
sentitems.ItemAdd += sentitems_ItemAdd;
```

and

```
void sentitems_ItemAdd(object item)
{
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
    DateTime x1 = mailItem.TaskStartDate;  // 5/7/2015
    DateTime x2 = mailItem.TaskDueDate;  // 5/7/2015
```

they have the values I expect.

Comment: this discovery being made using @RenniePet's OutlookSpy tool recommendation